# Creating and appending a DOM element with the content of another element

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes, appendchild, createelement

My code is as follows

```
  ;(function(window){
    var $description_window= document.querySelector('.mg_post_description'),
        $headings= document.querySelectorAll('.mg_blog_main_content h3'),
        $paragraph = document.createElement('p');
        for (var j = 0; j < $headings.length; j++) {
            var $headingChildren=$headings[j].cloneNode(true).childNodes;
            $paragraph.appendChild($headingChildren[j]);
       }
       $description_window.append($paragraph);
})(window);
```

Here what I am trying to do is; to copy the h3 tags of the content box. Then create a `paragraph` element. Then append the `p` tags with collected `h3` tags. However, I get the following error on running this.

Failed to execute `appendChild` on `Node`: parameter 1 is not of type `Node`.

```js
  ;(function(window){
    var $description_window= document.querySelector('.post_description'),
    
   $headings= document.querySelectorAll('.post_description h3'),
   $paragraph = document.createElement('p');
   
   for (var j = 0; j < $headings.length; j++) {
   
       var $headingChildren=$headings[j].cloneNode(true).childNodes;
            $paragraph.appendChild($headingChildren[j]);
       }
       
       $description_window.append($paragraph);
       
})(window);
```

```css
.post_description{

  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#555;
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  right:8%;
  
}

.post_description a {
  
  color:white;
}

.main_body{

  padding-top:40%;

}
```

```html
<div class="main_body">
    <h3>Testing one</h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

  <h3>Testing two</h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>


  <h3>Testing three</h3>

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>


  <h3>Testing four</h3>

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</div>

<div class="post_description"></div>
```

Could someone please explain why this occurs and how to solve this

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the element 'content box' html ?

Comment: The elements of the content box are simple h3 headings and p block text. I am trying to extract the h3 elements and display those as paragraph elements in another div.

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle

Comment: All I did was remove `childNodes` and all the fluff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
function addElem() {
    var mElem = document.querySelector('.mg_post_description')
    var hElems = document.getElementsByTagName('H3');
    var node = document.createElement("P");
    for (var i = 0; i < hElems.length; i++) {

        var textnode = document.createTextNode(hElems[i].innerHTML);
        var cloneElem = node.cloneNode(true);
        cloneElem.appendChild(textnode);
        mElem.appendChild(cloneElem);
    }
};

addElem()
```

Codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YVEzdJ

Comment: It actually works. However, could I ask if I can do the same thing by modifying the original code I posted here. Thanks and looking forward

Comment: Updated codepen-https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZKaEZe, Hope this works for you  :)

Comment: Thanks Sai for your help

Comment: No problem.. Glad my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d = document.querySelector('.desc'),
    h = document.querySelectorAll('.main h3');

h.forEach(function(n) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = n.cloneNode(true).innerHTML || '';
  d.append(p);
});
```

```css
.desc {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h3>First</h3>
  <h3>Second</h3>
  <h3>Third</h3>
</div>

<div class="desc">
</div>
```

Comment: This one duplicates the h3 elements inside the new div, not as p elements.

Comment: Could you please generate the duplicated elements in p tag ? Thanks

Comment: something like that?